# How did a user receive Tumbleweed after years of inactivity?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, tumbleweed-badge

A user received the [tumbleweed](/questions/tagged/tumbleweed) badge [about an hour ago](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/21/tumbleweed?userid=26603),
[on his question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27812/add-elements-to-collection-conditionally) asked more than 2 years ago.
How is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was an answer on that question up until about an hour ago when it was deleted by a moderator.